# List<T> vs. T list in F# gives type error

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I want a function that receives a `seq<DateTime*int>`  and returns a `DateTime*seq<DateTime*int>`. The first part of the tuple is the `DateTime` of the first element of the incoming argument, and the list is the rest of the elements.

I've tried to code this in F# this way, but it gives a compiler error:

```
static member TheFunc(lst: seq<DateTime*int>)=
    match lst with
    | (h_d, h_i)::tail -> (h_d,tail)
    | [] -> raise (new ArgumentException("lst"))
```

The error, highlighted in `(h_d, h_i)`, is:

```
The expression was expected to have type
    seq<DateTime*int>
but here has type
    'a list
```

If I use a list instead of a sequence in the signature:

```
static member TheFunc(lst: List<DateTime*int>)=
    match lst with
    | (h_d, h_i)::tail -> (h_d,tail)
    | [] -> raise (new ArgumentException("lst"))
```

With:

```
The expression was expected to have type
    List<DateTime*int>
but here has type
    'a list
```

Any idea why this doesn't work and how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to match a `seq` with a `list` (as the error says).  You want to use

```
static member TheFunc(lst: seq<DateTime*int>)=
    match lst |> List.ofSeq with
    | (h_d, h_i)::tail -> (h_d,tail)
    | [] -> raise (new ArgumentException("lst"))
```

(convert the list to a seq then pattern match).

Alternatively, use

```
static member TheFunc(lst: list<DateTime*int>)=
```

The lower case `l` in `list` is because you probably have `System.Collections.Generic` open, and the `List` there is not the same as the F# `list`

Comment: ok, cool, and what if I didn't want to use List.ofSeq, how could I change the type of the argument to be a list?

Answer (score 2):

Use `(DateTime * int) list` instead of `List<DateTime * int>`.

The types `List<T>` and `T list` are different if you opened `System.Collections.Generic`. Remarkably, if you didn't, they're not!

If you did, then `List<int>` is an instance of the mutable lists typically used in C#:

```
> open System.Collections.Generic   
> let t0 = typeof<List<int>>
val t0 : Type = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
```

And `int list` is an instance of the immutable lists typically used in F#:

```
> let t1 = typeof<int list>
val t1 : Type = Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[System.Int32]
```

Confusingly, if you did *not* `open System.Collections.Generic`, they are the same:

```
(* New session *)
> let t0 = typeof<List<int>>
val t0 : Type = Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[System.Int32]
> let t1 = typeof<int list>
val t1 : Type = Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[System.Int32]
```